# Suppress result sets from trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a sql statement that first updates, then selects:

```
  UPDATE myTable 
  SET field1=@someValue
  WHERE field2=@someValue2

  SELECT 1 returnValue
```

The process that consumes the reults of this statement is expecting a single result set, simple enough.

The problem arises because an update trigger was added to the table that produces a result set, i.e. it selects like so:

```
 SELECT t_field1, t_field2, t_field3 FROM t_table
```

The obvious solution is to split up the statments.  Unfortunatley, the real world implementation of this is complex and to be avoided if possible.  The trigger is also nessecary and cannot be disabled.

Is there a way to supress the results from the update, returning only the value from the select statement?

Comment: the problem is the update trigger returning a resultset...

Comment: How do you consume the result? What is the client?

Comment: (1) The trigger returns a *result set* or a count?  (You should have `set NOCOUNT ON` in the trigger).  (2) Fix your stored procedure to return the value as an `OUTPUT` argument rather than through a result set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability to return result sets from triggers is deprecated in SQL Server 2012 and will be removed in a future version (maybe even in SQL Server 2016, but probably in the next version). Change your trigger to return the data in some other way. If it is needed just for debugging, use PRINT instead of SELECT. If it is needed for some other reasons, insert the data into a temporary table and perform the SELECT from the calling procedure (only when needed).